# font awesome asterisk wraps

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using font awesome with bootstrap framework. Whenever I mark a field as required, the asterisk (fa-asterisk) shows up correctly. However, it shows up wrapped beneath the text input. Some things I have tried:

1. `.fa { display:inline;  // also tried inline-block`
2. Marking the container `div` (form-group) of the input fields with `overflow:hidden`:

   ```
   .form-group
   {
       overflow:hidden;
       overflow-wrap:inherit;
   }
   ```

Nothing seems to work, still wraps the asterisk below the input field. Changing the size of the input field container (from col-md-6 to something smaller) also does not help.

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
.formValidation({
      message: 'This value is not valid',
      //err: {
      //    container: 'tooltip'
      //},
      framework: 'bootstrap',
      icon: {
        //required: 'glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk',
        //valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        //invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        //validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        required: 'fa fa-asterisk',
        valid: 'fa fa-check',
        invalid: 'fa fa-times',
        validating: 'fa fa-refresh'

      }
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
.fa-asterisk:before {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: inherit;
  color: darkred;
  font-size: 7px;
  content: "\f069";
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="patientSSN">Patient SSN</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="patientSSN" id="patientSSN" placeholder="" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem that’s occurring. By showing your code, it will be easier for us to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What tags are you using?  Why do you need to use FA for an asterisk?

Comment: see http://formvalidation.io/examples/showing-required-icon/

Answer (score 0):

Please show your code for complete solution, for quick solution you can do this :

```
.validator{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```